# Timespan Arithmetics to predict tide

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to predict tide in c# using a formula given below:

[image]

The program was already done in excel, however when translating it to c# I am encountering some problems.

---

This is the formula in excel:

`=PI()*((C18)/(C19)+1)`

Cells C18 and C19 just contain subtraction of two date cells each

---

In C# I am having trouble finding A.
There are 2 problematic areas in finding A.
**Problem1:** When I do `(t - t1)/(t2 - t1)` the answer in C# is 0, but in excel the answer is 1.
**Problem 2:** the +1 at the end of equation. How do you add a number to timeSpan(in excel this works, maybe because they parse it as a datetime value?)

---

Here is my code:

```
DateTime t = new DateTime(2016, 6, 21, 13, 41, 00);
DateTime t1 = new DateTime(2016, 6, 21, 7, 13, 00);
DateTime t2 = new DateTime(2016, 6, 21, 13, 57, 00);
double h1 = 1.421;
double h2 = 2.337;
double h2_minus_h1 = h2 - h1;
TimeSpan t_minus_t1 = TimeSpan.FromTicks(t.Subtract(t1).Ticks);
TimeSpan t2_minus_t1 = TimeSpan.FromTicks(t2.Subtract(t1).Ticks);
TimeSpan MainCalculationForA = TimeSpan.FromTicks((t.Subtract(t1).Ticks) / (t2.Subtract(t1).Ticks));
MessageBox.Show(MainCalculationForA.ToString());
```

---

The answer for this which is `(t - t1)/(t2 - t1)` is: `00:00:00`, while in excel it is just 1
Note:The formula is taken from here
[tide prediction pdf](http://www.linz.govt.nz/sites/default/files/docs/hydro/tidal-info/tide-tables/mfth-between-hlw.pdf)

note:`(t - t1)` and `(t2 - t1)` both have exactly the same answer in both C# and excel. So why the difference in answer upon division?

Comment: Problem 2, You can add to a TimeSpan using the Add Method I believe. You can create a new timespan of the duration you want and add it this way.

Comment: Problem 1, I think because you are dividing the Ticks, which are integers, you'll get 0 because you can't get a fractional result with integers.

Comment: Thanks, Problem 1 has been solved from Niyoko's asnswer. Now I just need a solution to Problem 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PDF provided, `t`, `t1` and `t2` are in **decimal hours**, so you need `.TotalHours` instead

```
DateTime t = new DateTime(2016, 6, 21, 13, 41, 00);
DateTime t1 = new DateTime(2016, 6, 21, 7, 13, 00);
DateTime t2 = new DateTime(2016, 6, 21, 13, 57, 00);
double h1 = 1.421;
double h2 = 2.337;

double t_min_t1 = (t - t1).TotalHours;
double t2_min_t1 = (t2 - t1).TotalHours;

double A = Math.PI*(t_min_t1/t2_min_t1 + 1);
double h = h1 + (h2 - h1)*((Math.Cos(A) + 1)/2);

MessageBox.Show(h.ToString());
```

The end result is `2.33345960154238`.

Comment: It's still the same, 00:00:00 is the answer.

Comment: `t_minus_t1/t2_minus_t1` is a `double`, how can you got `00:00:00`?

Comment: missed  the MessageBox part. but can you tell how to add 1 as well. I can only  mark this as the correct one after that

Comment: Well since this is now handled as a double this should work when you add 1 as well. I will try